# Showing cones under a functor are cones over the opposite functor

Tags: category-theory

I am reading from Riehl's Category Theory in Context, and have a doubt about cones and cocones.

Say, $J$ is an "indexing" category. Then, I am trying to show that a cone under $F:J \rightarrow C$ is a cone over $F^{op}:J^{op} \rightarrow C^{op}$ (Riehl, Section 3.1). Therefore, if I consider a morphism $f:k \rightarrow j$ in $J$, then I want to show that, given a cone under F,

[image: Hello]

it gives a cone $\psi^{op}$ over $F^{op}$,

[image]

Therefore, given $\psi_k = \psi_j \cdot Ff$, I want to show $\psi^{op}_j = F^{op}f \cdot \psi^{op}_k$. Now, $F^{op}f$ is a morphism $Fk \rightarrow Fj$, and indeed equals $Ff$. Moreover, $F^{op}$ is the same over objects of $J$. So, we get

[image]

Now, I am not sure what to say about $\psi^{op}$. I suppose it is a natural transformation $J_c^{op} \rightarrow F^{op}$, where $J_c^{op}$ is the constant functor from $J^{op}$ to $C^{op}$ at $c$. But how do I (a) define it using $\psi$ and (b) show commutativity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second triangle is not what you want to show. $f$ is an arrow in the indexing category $J,$ so in $J^{op}$ you should have the arrow $f^{op}: j \to k.$ After all, nobody ever asserted the existence of any arrows between $Fk$ and $Fk$ in $C^{op}.$

Then you should see that commutativity of each of the triangles is about precisely the same thing, the only difference being where you draw the head of each arrow.